# How to import TrackballControls from three.js module using react?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, import, three.js

I am using react js boiler plate (create-react-app) and imported three.js. I am trying to use TrackballControls for a particular project but it isn't working. It throws an error like "Attempted import error: 'TrackballControls' is not exported from 'three' (imported as 'THREE')" . Now I understand that it is in the examples folder and it's not an official export if I correctly understood from the forum. Some one please help me with this, how do I import TrackballControls in a react component? Help will be highly appreciated!

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import * as THREE from 'three'
const OrbitControls = require('three-orbit-controls')(THREE)



import "../src/assets/sass/home.scss"



const X = () => {

const [y, setY] = useState(0)
const [ masses, setMasses ] = useState([])

let parent, renderer, scene, camera, controls



useEffect(() => {

    // renderer
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer()
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight )
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement )

    // scene
    scene = new THREE.Scene()

    // camera
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 40, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 100 )
    camera.position.set( 20, 20, 20 )

    // controls
    controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera, sphere )
    controls.minDistance = 5
    controls.maxDistance = 250
    controls.enableDamping = true; // an animation loop is required when either damping or auto-rotation are enabled
    controls.dampingFactor = 0.05;

    // axes
    // scene.add(new THREE.AxisHelper( 20 ))

    // geometry
    let geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 2, 8, 6, 0, 6.3, 0, 3.1)

    // material
    let material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        wireframe: true,
        wireframeLinewidth: 1
    })

    let sphere = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material )

    // parent
    parent = new THREE.Object3D()
    scene.add( parent )
    scene.add( sphere )

    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame( animate )
        parent.rotation.z += 0.01
        controls.update()
        renderer.render( scene, camera )
    }

    animate()


}

,[])




return <div></div>
}

export default X
```

Comment: show your code so that we can follow it and it will help to fix your issue

Comment: @blueseal, sorry for that, I updated the code in my enquiry, please see.

Comment: @blueseal they have migrated some of their modules - I saw it from here - https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration-Guide

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know there's no one here to see this but I'm posting my solution if someone comes across this issue in the future. So here's what I figured out -

I haven't mentioned in my question that I was using a SSR (server side render) react framework called next.js. The import works perfectly fine with a pure react app. But in server side frameworks, the import related stuff should be done inside the useEffect (or componentDidMount) along with the rest of the threejs stuff. So I dynamically imported it like this -

```
let dynamicallyImportPackage = async () => {
    let TrackballControls

    await import('three/examples/jsm/controls/TrackballControls')
    // you can now use the package in here
    .then(module => {
        TrackballControls = module.TrackballControls
    })
    .catch(e => console.log(e))

    return TrackballControls
}
```

then, I used it in my useEffect like so -

```
let TrackbackControls = await dynamicallyImportPackage()


    // controls
    controls = new TrackbackControls(camera, container)
    controls.minDistance = 5
    controls.maxDistance = 250
```

Arigato Gosaimasu!

Answer (score 6):

All JavaScript files from the examples directory are now available as ES6 modules in the `three` npm package. There is actually a guide that explains how you can import them in your application:

https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Import-via-modules

For your particular case, it would look like so:

```js
import { TrackballControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/TrackballControls.js';
```

Notice that third-party packages like `three-orbit-controls` are not necessary anymore. When using the modules from the `three` package, it's guaranteed that you work with the latest (and supported) versions.

`three.js R109`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried importing like that, but it's throwing this error -  [link](https://imgur.com/a/3KP3iw5)

Comment: Please check the link - i posted an image link @Mugen87

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with webpack. Since using webpack is not a `three.js` related issue, I suggest you try to find out how to use ES6 modules with webpack. Notice that you can't use `require` with ES6 modules. You have to work with `import` instead.

Comment: My bad, i forgot to mention, i am using a next.js framework (server side react) with a custom express server. I guess that has problems with loading the file as js or something. I don't know webpack myself. I guess I'd have to learn it and hope I can fix this issue. :(